# Nodejs localhost keeps loading my function

Tags: sql, node.js, sqlite

Good morning to everyone,

Please I would be so grateful if you could provide a little help for me. I am already stuck for long time with this issue.

I have a function which does not stop loading my localhost after this function is triggered. I did not figure out so far how to fix it.

Any help would be perfect.

This is my code:

```
// Copy scene
router.post('/copy', function(req,res,call) {

if( req.param('scene') !== undefined ){

db.serialize(function () {

 db.run("CREATE TABLE temp_table as SELECT * FROM scene where id=?", req.param('scene'));
 db.run("UPDATE temp_table SET id = NULL, user_id = (SELECT id FROM users WHERE email =?)",GLOBAL.email);
 db.run("INSERT INTO scene SELECT * FROM temp_table");
 db.run("DROP TABLE temp_table");
    if(error) {
        console.log(error);
    } 
 });

 db.close();

 }
 });
```

Thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever browser sends any request to a server it expects a response. if it doesn't get any response it will be stuck with the timeout.

You need to send the response to terminate the `request` if you are not doing next execution with `callback call` or if you are expecting next manipulation then `replace res.send() to call(error parameter,success parameter)`.

```
router.post('/copy', function(req, res, call) {

    if (req.param('scene') !== undefined) {

        db.serialize(function() {

            db.run("CREATE TABLE temp_table as SELECT * FROM scene where id=?", req.param('scene'));
            db.run("UPDATE temp_table SET id = NULL, user_id = (SELECT id FROM users WHERE email =?)", GLOBAL.email);
            db.run("INSERT INTO scene SELECT * FROM temp_table");
            db.run("DROP TABLE temp_table");
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
                res.send(error);//send response if error
                //or call(error);
            }
            res.send({message:'success'});//send response if success
            //or call(null,whatever you want to pass)
        });
        db.close();

    }
});
```

Comment: But dont I need to place the request after the database is closed? Because the browser is still stuck even though I send the response just as you proposed. Even if I completely remove the `if (error)` statement it keeps waiting for response. Literally I tried to call the response everywhere in this code.

Comment: Are you sure you are requesting same route? debug it.

Comment: Okay perfect thanks! That was the problem. Now I need to just got a request which would reload the current page, but `res.render()` or `res.redirect()` does not work for me. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: In question you  are sending json object. But now you want to render a page or redirect. You should configure it properly. It's not part of this question.

Comment: I have just solved it by myself, but thanks for the effort ;)

Answer (score 0):

You must either call the callback `call()` to pass on control to next middleware, or render and end the response using `res.end()` once your middleware logic is done.

Please see: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html